# How to pass extra parameters to the VCS command line in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

So I want to pass some extra parameters to VCS command (in my case HG) when pulling down source.

But the "Edit VCS Root" screen does not let me add extra parameters.

Comment: What parameters do you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set this option in UI. You can write a wrapper for hg command and specify path to this wrapper in the `Path to hg` option in VCS root settings. Wrapper can be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    init|pull|clone)
        command=$1;
        shift;
        hg $command --insecure $*
        ;;
    *)
        hg $*
        ;;
esac
```

If you use an agent-side checkout you will have to have this wrapper on both: TeamCity server and the agents. Also if you think it's useful to have this option in UI feel free to create an issue in the [tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com).

Comment: Is this possible if dont own the server? i am trying to get it working on codebetterCI

Comment: only if owners create a wrapper :(